# SQL Trigger time check + - 1hour

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need to write a trigger that will check if the new added date&time is lesser or greater at least by one hour than every row in the table. Thanks in advance. It should look something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER task_change_date
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON task_history
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.change_date > change_date by HOUR or :new.change_date < change_date by HOUR)
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'This time is already occupied' );
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: If the validity of the data in one row depends on the data in other rows, that generally implies that you have a normalization issue that should be resolved rather than trying to work around it in a trigger.  To avoid a mutating table error, you can build three triggers and a package (or temporary table) and add a lot of complexity to your environment.  That generally isn't the right solution though.

Comment: It sounds like you need a uniqueness check based on the hour of `change_date` - you could do this with a unique function-based index on `TRUNC(change_date,'HH24')`.